# Scripting Static Routes in Routing and Remote Access

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, static-routes

[This Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469825.aspx) explains how to create a static route for IPv4 in Microsoft's Routing and Remote Access with the MMC snap-in.

How can I script this, either through PowerShell or VBScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes added via the mmc are simply added to the server routing table. So you can use a standard route add command inside a batch file

```
route add <address> <masK> <gateway> <metric> <interface>
```

However they won't show in the mmc if you add them this way, I'm not sure if that is a requirement from your question (Not enough rep to comment)

EDIT

```
netsh routing dump >> routes.txt
```

Will dump the config for RRAS and you can add the following lines for each route.

```
add persistentroute dest=<IP> mask=<MASK> name="<Interface Name>" nhop=<Nexthop> proto=NONDOD metric=256 view=both
set persistentroute dest=<IP> mask=<MASK> name="<Interface Name>" nhop=<Nexthop> proto=NONDOD metric=256 view=both
```

Then Import using

```
netsh exec routes.txt >> import_log.txt
```